# How can i use flutter StreamBuilder whith Card and Listtile

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, stream-builder

I’m working on my first task on Flutter which is small Job portal.
    I faced  problem I cant handel it 
    I want turn this static code to Stream Builder Query snapshot to show all the Jobs form database 
    can any one help

This is layout of Jobs and where I want to add the stream

```
 class _HotJobsState extends State<HotJobs> {
  List jobs;
  @override
  void initState() {
    jobs = getHotJobs();
    super.initState();
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ListTile makeListTile(JobsHot job) => ListTile(
      isThreeLine: true,
      title: Text(
        job.title,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      subtitle: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            job.companyName,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    ' Deadline:',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    job.deadline,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    ' Experience:',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    job.experience,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      ' Education:',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      job.education,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      trailing: Image(
        width: 40.0,
        height: 40.0,
        image: AssetImage(job.image),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => JobDetailsPage(jobsHot: job)));
      },
    );

    Card makeCard(JobsHot job) => Card(
      elevation: 8.0,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 200.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: makeListTile(job),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, titleText: 'Hot Jobs'),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                  spreadRadius: 10,
                  blurRadius: 20,
                  offset: Offset(0, 7), // changes position of shadow
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 0.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '175',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          ' Hot Jobs',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: jobs.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return makeCard(jobs[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and if he clicked on any Job it should open its information ?

This is how it should to be the UI 
[Jobs Layout Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8d7I.png)

and This is the Jobs Module and some of static Jobs but now i had many jobs on Fire store and i want to retrive it all on this layout

````
 class JobsHot {
  String title;
  String companyName;
  String deadline;
  String experience;
  String education;
  String vacancies;
  String salary;
  String location;
  String image;
  String responsibility;
  String requirement;
  String salaryBreakdown;

  JobsHot({
    this.title,
    this.companyName,
    this.deadline,
    this.experience,
    this.education,
    this.image,
    this.vacancies,
    this.salary,
    this.location,
    this.responsibility,
    this.requirement,
    this.salaryBreakdown,
  });
}

List getHotJobs() {
  return [
    JobsHot(
      title: "Android and iOS Developer",
      companyName: "Quality Feeds Limited",
      deadline: "Feb 29, 2020",
      experience: "1-2 years",
      education: "Bachelor of Science(BSc) in CSE",
      image: 'assets/images/letters/q9.png',
      vacancies: '02',
      salary: '12000-15000(monthly)',
      location: 'Cairo, Maady',
      responsibility:
          "• Develop high-quality android applications, ensuring proper software design and architecture.\n\n"
          "• Identify, prioritize and execute tasks in the software development life cycle.\n\n"
          "• Debug existing source code and polish feature sets.\n\n"
          "• Have understanding of software development methodologies. \n\n"
          "• Work on bug fixing and improving application performance.\n\n"
          "• Work independently when required.\n\n"
          "• Continuously learn and improve skills.\n\n"
          "• Attention to detail is essential and all tasks must be carried out to the highest standard.\n\n",
      requirement: "• Age 23 to 30 years.\n\n"
          "• Sound knowledge in Object Oriented Programming(i.e. OOPs) concepts.\n\n"
          "• Must have a strong knowledge of Android SDK, different versions of Android, how to deal with different screen sizes and applications with complex UI and Work robustly with Android UI design principles, patterns, and best practices.\n\n"
          "• Must have experience with OOP, Kotlin, Android Studio, Gradle, ProGuard and GIT/SVN, Unit testing.\n\n"
          "• Must have experience for development and integration of API to Mobile Applications.\n\n"
          "• Experience with offline storage, threading, and performance tuning. \n\n"
          "• Familiarity with RESTful APIs to connect Android applications to back-end services.\n\n",
      salaryBreakdown: "• 12000-15000(monthly).\n\n"
          "• Mobile bill, Provident fund, Weekly 2 holidays, Insurance.\n\n"
          "• Lunch Facilities: Full Subsidize.\n\n"
          "• Salary Review: Yearly.\n\n"
          "• Festival Bonus: 2.\n\n",
    ), ```
````

some one right this code and i try to modify on it so i dont Know what is (Jobshot job) refer to on the Card and List 
    i try to get snapshots and if it has data i save it on List but i cant use This list to take the salary and name and other things Up there on   ListTile makeListTile(JobsHot job) => ListTile because its out of scope

```
please if any one help me to turn this code to reade from firestore and present it on this UI  its my graduation project and im stuck with this
```

Comment: Means you didnt write the code for fetching data from firebase?

Answer (score 0):

use FutureBuilder Widget for stream request like

```
final builder = FutureBuilder(
    future: _future,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
        return _buildLoader();
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return _buildError();
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return _buildDataView();
      }     
      return _buildNoData();
});
```

a full example is in this link [Future Builder with list view example](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9)

Comment: i already used stream builder with Querysnapshot  same this way 
im ask about this code up there ? i used if condition like you and save value in list and return the builder but i cant extract the text and img and other thing from this list because i declared it inside if so it wodnt apper up ther in Listtile

Comment: if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<JobsHot> _jobs = [];
            for (var doc in snapshot.data.documents) {
              var data = doc.data;

             _jobs.add(JobsHot(
                  companyName: data['FirmName'],
                  title: data['JobTitle'],
                  requirement: data['JobRequirements'],
                  salary: data['Salary'],
                  deadline: data['Deadline'],
                  description: data['JobDescription'],
                  education: data['Education'],
               ));
             print(_jobs);
            }

Comment: i need to now job up there refer to what because its not my code :( im trying to deal with it

Comment: sorry bro i don't completely take your question!!